# Unable to set headers in API Automation

Tags: automation, request-headers

I have created a class to make POST call, but instead of 202 I am receiving 400 (Bad request in the response.)
Payload data is correct, it must be an issue to set Headers while making POST call.

```
public void postIBCTNonCGScenario() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        restClient = new RestClient();
        HashMap<String, String> addHeaderMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        addHeaderMap.put("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        addHeaderMap.put("Host", "<calculated when request is sent>");
        System.out.println("Headers" + addHeaderMap);

        String filePath = new File(xml file path);
        closeableHttpResponse = restClient.post(url, filePath, addHeaderMap);
        System.out.println("URL " + url);

        //Response code
        int statusCode= closeableHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Statuscode: " + statusCode);
        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, testBase.RESPONSE_CODE_STATUS_202);
    }

public CloseableHttpResponse post(String url, String entityString, HashMap<String, String> headerMap)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); // POST call

        // Used to define payload
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(entityString));
        System.out.println("POST Payload is : " + entityString);

        // for Headers
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headerMap.entrySet()) {
            httpPost.addHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
//          httpPost.getHeaders(String.valueOf(headerMap));
        }
        System.out.println("POST API Headers : " + httpPost.getAllHeaders().toString());
        CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        return closeableHttpResponse;
    }
```

Expecting to create data with POST call.